# Unable to call value_counts on a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I created a new column in my dataset like so:

```
df['new_col'] = [ True if v > 0 else False for v in df.old_col ]
```

When I call value_counts() on the new column, it only works when I do

```
df['new_col'].value_counts() # works fine
```

but

```
df.new_col.value_counts()
```

gives this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

I'm pretty confused as to why this happens...can I not use dot syntax on new columns? Any advice much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: By any chance, did you set 'new_col' by df.new_col = ... instead of df['new_col'] = ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by Alexander, it looks like you've set the attribute rather than a new Series. You *must* assign a new column using bracket notation:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df['C'] = [1, 2]

In [13]: type(df.C)
Out[13]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Without it you are just assigning an attribute (and pandas doesn't know you want this to be a column):

```
In [14]: df.D = [1, 2]

In [15]: type(df.D)
Out[15]: list
```

You can't access this attribute using bracket notation:

```
In [16]: df['D']
KeyError: 'D'
```

For this reason, I like to use bracket notation *consistently* throughout my code, that way I - and the reader - know it's a column... ([explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

Note: This is actually very useful behaviour, as (for one thing) it allows you to set meta-data to a DataFrame. Similarly you can assign an attribute (or method) to `pd.DataFrame` so that it can be used for any DataFrame.

```
In [21]: pd.DataFrame.x = 1

In [22]: df.x
Out[22]: 1
```

*(This can occasionally be useful, but use this very sparingly!!!)*

Comment: Thank you! This helped me figure out the issue: `df['new_col'] = [ True if v > 0 else False for v in df.old_col ]` uses bracket notation for column assignment, but the reference to the **old column** used dot notation. When I do `df['new_col'] = [ True if v > 0 else False for v in df['old_col'] ]
` it works!

Comment: @NatalieArellano Always use bracket notation! I think dot notation was introduced purely for showing off / tab-completion when doing presentations! :p